# Disable error/warning/problems banner (peek?) in VSCode for command "Go to Next Problem"

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

When using "Go to Next Problem" in VScode (Alt-F8 by default), a peek/banner is shown below the problematic line describing the problem.

Yet in about 90% of the cases I know anyway what the problem is and just want to get rid of the banner, so my typical key-sequence is not Alt-F8 but Alt-F8, Esc to immediately get rid of the banner.

Is there a way to prevent the banner to show up? I searched settings for "peek" and "problem" but could not find anything. Also a different "go to" command does not seem to be available.

Is there some way to do that?

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing

Comment: This has driven me crazy since day one of VSCode years ago. It's so distracting when my code moves around to make space for the banner. And like you say, I already know what the problem is. And the problem text is already in the status bar!

Comment: Hoping for an answer to this vexing issue.